# Checking the continuity and differentiability of a function defined on a non-connected set of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

let $f:\mathbb{R}-\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=|x|$.

Is the function continous and differentiable.

I think the function Is continuous because $\lim_{x \to 0^+}|x|=0=\lim_{x \to 0^-}|x|$, we need not worry about $f\left(0\right)$ because it is not defined.

However $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f' \left(x\right) \neq \lim_{x \to 0^-}f' \left(x\right)$,

So it is not differentiable.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Notice that $0$ does not lie in the domain of $f$.

Comment: @Yes I know...so it is continuous? Isn't it?

Comment: Consider $F:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $F(x) = |x|$. Is it continuous? Do you know that the restriction of a continuous functions remains continuous?

Comment: @Yes Bro...I know that...Do not use any new statements...tell me if I am correct with my reasoning?

Comment: @filnpellizieri Please use basic definitions

Comment: You seem to have proved it's not differentiable at zero. So now I ask you: would you **expect** it to be differentiable at a point that's not even in its domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry about $x=0$ because it is not in your domain.

For any other point the function is both continuous and differentiable.

Comment: It is continuous at $x=0$? Yes or No?

Comment: No, it is not continuous at x=0. For continuity we have to have f(0)=0, which we do not have due to the domain being $R-\{0\}$